# most efficent way to select a matrix of data excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to select a matrix of data strating from 'A1' but with a variable row and column range.

I am using the following code to do such task

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

is there a quicker way to get to the same range selected?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a **block** of data and the upper left-hand corner is **A1**, then:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the end point, then yes, you can define two ranges within the "Range" reference and it will use one as the start point, and the other as the end point, e.g.

```
Range(Range("A1"),Range("Z10")).Copy
```

is analogous to

```
Range("A1:Z10").Copy
```

similarly, if you have a range RangeX, you can use

```
Range(RangeX, RangeX.offset(2,2)).Copy
```

Which will always select a square range of 3x3 cells originating from "RangeX"